# Files were deleted when I used `mv` command from disk to usb with ubuntu live cd

Tags: ubuntu, usb, filesystems, livecd

I have a computer with Ubuntu 18.04. The Desktop was broken, so I decided to reinstall the OS.
I wanted to recover my important files, so I used Ubuntu 18.04 Live CD. When I tried to move the files from my disk to a USB Drive, (Using the live cd), I got `permission denied`. I decided to do that using terminal. I did right click in both of the folders, and clicked "Open in terminal". Then I took their paths, and did `sudo mv <source> <target>`, when the source is the path of my files inside the Live CD, and the target is the path of the USB. But after that, the files just disappeared from my drive, and didn't appear in the USB. There is something that I can do? These files are very important.

Thank's!

Comment: Is your device capable of writing to the CD-ROM drive?

Comment: Yes. Do you think that my files are inside the Live CD?

Comment: But I don't think that it possible to write data to the Live CD after it's burned

Comment: I wouldn't know, that's the only thing I think could have happened because technically CDs are just storage devices.